# "They have harmed oneself" is wrong in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, definition

They **have harmed oneself**? It should be better instead **they have harmed themselves?** Or it's referring to they are harming someone in the highlighted part?

> retaliation NOUN
>
> mass noun
>
> 1The action of returning a military attack; counter-attack.
>
> ‘the bombings are believed to be in retaliation for the trial of 15
> suspects’
>
> 1.1 The action of harming someone **because they have harmed oneself**; revenge.
>
> ‘she rejected as preposterous any suggestion
> that she had acted in retaliation’

[Retaliation (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/retaliation)

Answer (score 3):

*Retaliation* is when you do something to somebody else because they have done something to you. Although the form of the retaliation might not be so literal, it has the same sense as the idiom *an eye for an eye*.

In the definition in the question, *oneself* doesn't refer to *someone* or *them*; instead, it refers to *you*.

It could be rephrased in the following way:

> the action of harming someone because they have harmed <sup><s>oneself</s></sup> **you**

I find that more comprehensible in this context, even though I understand why the dictionary doesn't want to use the specific *you*.

Although *oneself* isn't as natural as *you* in this definition, it's still grammatical.

[**Oneself**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oneself) can be thought of as *one's self* or *one's own self*:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : a person's self : one's own self —used reflexively as object of a preposition or verb or for emphasis in various constructions
>     // It is important to have good feelings about *oneself*.
> **2** : one's normal, healthy, or sane condition or self
>     // the need to protect *oneself* from danger

But since in this case it's being used to reflexively refer to the second-person *you* (at least by inference), you cannot replace it with either *themselves* or the increasingly frequent *themself*, both of which reflexively refer to the third-person *they*.